# What can we say about correlation coefficients?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

If we are looking at sales and inventory data with a correlation of 50%, what can I conclude? My intuition tells me that 50 % of the movement in one of the variables is attributed to the others movement and vice versa. But I want to be able to explain this to people who do not use stats verb-age.

Two things: Is my intuition correct and how can I explain this relationship?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct - provided that both sales and inventory are roughly normally distributed.

If your audience if geometrically inclined, you can tell them that correlation is the cosine of the angle between the vectors (in the Hilbert space). 
So, the correlation of 50% means the angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ ($60^o$).
Moving along one of lines means half the movement along the other.